Underflow issue only by replacing the input variable of Exp with numbers
I was facing an underflow issue with Exp[]. I was able to fix that by following the suggestion: New General::munfl error and loss of precision
However, when the argument of Exp are variables and I try to evaluate the function replacing the variables with numbers the issue continues. Below please find a reduced version of my notebook to show you the issue I am facing. I was wondering if you have any suggestions to fix that.
Many many thanks in advance
    params = {
   f -> 2.516,
   \[Omega]0 -> 2 \[Pi]*f,
   \[Omega] -> 100};

(compiledExp[x_Real] := #[x]) &@Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Exp[x]];
(compiledExp[x_Complex] := #[x]) &@Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, Exp[x]];

bigExp[x_?MachineNumberQ] := Exp[SetPrecision[x, $MachinePrecision]];
munderflowExp[x_] := 
  With[{y = compiledExp[x]},(*Machine evaluation*)
   If[y == 0,(*Condition for machine underflow*)
    bigExp[x],(*Action to take on machine underflow converting to a \
bignum result*)
    y(*Machine precision result when underflow does not occur*)]];
Unprotect[Exp];
Exp[x_?MachineNumberQ] := munderflowExp[x];
Protect[Exp];

ReplaceRepeated[#, params] &@( Exp[-(\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)^2])

Exp[(-(\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)^2) /. {\[Omega] -> 
    2 \[Pi]*2.516, \[Omega]0 -> 100}]

Exp[-7088.209643337722`]

( Exp[ReplaceRepeated[#, params] &@(-(\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)^2)])


The problem is that Exp[x] (for symbolic x) evaluates to Power[E, x]. So your special definition gets circumvented. What is is you're actually trying to solve here?

@SjoerdSmit, thank you very much for getting back to me. I have been trying to plot an expression and receiving the underflow-like warning. Initially, I gave little attention to it. Then, I realized it impacts the accuracy of the function even outside the range of values where the function assumes crazy values. I figured out that the Exp function, part of the expression I am trying to plot, causes the issue.
Would defining a special function for Power[E, x] also solve the problem?

I think it's probably the wrong way to go. Why not simply do your calculations in arbitrary-precision arithmetic? That's the correct solution to the problem if you ask me. If you don't want underflow, don't use machine precision.

@SjoerdSmit, thank you very much.  What is the easiest way to perform calculations in arbitrary-precision arithmetic? Can I set it up at the beginning of the notebook? Thanks again!

Just define all of your input numbers as arbitrary precision numbers (like 2.516`20) or exact numbers (like 100). As long as you don't introduce machine numbers, it should all just work. Also don't use Compile, since it won't work with arbitrary precision.

@SjoerdSmit, got it. Thanks so much!
